# No Implementation found for native in ndk

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am struck with an error, using the jni ... I have a simple native method in android activity class and created header for that and implemented the c file for that...unable to find the mistake pls help

Here are the files that I have

Activity

```
static{
        System.loadLibrary("fluidsynth");
    }



    private  native String textOverjni();
```

Header file

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO */

#ifndef _Included_com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO
#define _Included_com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_MODE_PRIVATE
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_MODE_PRIVATE 0L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_MODE_WORLD_READABLE
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_MODE_WORLD_READABLE 1L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE 2L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_MODE_APPEND
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_MODE_APPEND 32768L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_BIND_AUTO_CREATE
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_BIND_AUTO_CREATE 1L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_BIND_DEBUG_UNBIND
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_BIND_DEBUG_UNBIND 2L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_BIND_NOT_FOREGROUND 4L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE 1L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY 2L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_CONTEXT_RESTRICTED
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_CONTEXT_RESTRICTED 4L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_RESULT_CANCELED
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_RESULT_CANCELED 0L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_RESULT_OK
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_RESULT_OK -1L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_RESULT_FIRST_USER
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_RESULT_FIRST_USER 1L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_DEFAULT_KEYS_DISABLE
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_DEFAULT_KEYS_DISABLE 0L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_DEFAULT_KEYS_DIALER
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_DEFAULT_KEYS_DIALER 1L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_DEFAULT_KEYS_SHORTCUT
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_DEFAULT_KEYS_SHORTCUT 2L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_LOCAL 3L
#undef com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_GLOBAL
#define com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_DEFAULT_KEYS_SEARCH_GLOBAL 4L
/*
 * Class:     com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO
 * Method:    textOverjni
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_textOverjni
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

C file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <MyFluidSynthO.h>


JNIEXPORT jstring  Java_com_example_fluidsynthtest_MyFluidSynthO_textOverjni
  (JNIEnv* env, jobject obj){
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello Worlddd from MyFluidSynth1 !");
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include  $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE   := fluidsynth
#LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/include\
$(LOCAL_PATH)/include/fluidsynth

LOCAL_SRC_FILES +:= \
    MyFluidSynthO.c
#LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include  $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Can you include the error message you see in logcat?

Answer (score 2):

For "No implementation found" issues while building Android NDK, you can look into following links which explain the reasons and solutions for these problems.

[Android NDK C++ JNI (no implementation found for native...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197889/android-ndk-c-jni-no-implementation-found-for-native?rq=1)

[android ndk jni No implementation found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814143/android-ndk-jni-no-implementation-found-error?rq=1)

["No implementation found for native" error when calling C function - Android NDK - Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505927/no-implementation-found-for-native-error-when-calling-c-function-android-ndk?rq=1)

Answer (score -4):

build the **.so** file once again by **ndk_build**